# How to set a specific default charset for Multi Collation for a table

Tags: php, mysql

I create a table with different collation column that included:
utf8_persian_ci
cp1256

Why different collation? Because some of them address and correct charset for PHP that be able create Persian folder/files is windows-1256 therefore I thought I need to set charset cp1256 for saving path into mysql.

It shows ???? instead of farsi characters When I fetch rows from the table to show in PHP. My default charset sets to UTF8.

Now what is the problem that row store with ??? or php shows ??? instead persian keywords?

Comment: why you don't store it in UTF-8? I suggest convert strings into default UTF-8 collation use `iconv` method and store it into MySQL